# How to render Wiris mathematical expressions in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, ckeditor

I have successfully integrated Wiris plugin into Ckeditor. Every thing works just fine except the front view. I am programming with laravel5 and using Angularjs to handle my views.

When I create a mathematical expression for example `(x - 1)` Angularjs will present it as `x-1` .

I even used `ng-bind-html` to no avail. But at the level of the editor everything is fine such that I can create and save it without any problems.
I am using Wiris for Ckeditor and PHP.

When I use the `{!!  !!}` for the blade template engine and it is just fine. How do I archive this in AngularJs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that by default WIRIS plugin works in full MathML mode (http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/full-mathml-mode) storing MathML in the database. You need to include WIRISplugin.js as detailed in the documentation link previously mentioned.